# PHP MySQL function dies

Tags: php, mysql

Ive written my function just to check if the database connection is working.

And it seems like he cant connect to my database, thats no problem, but he dies at the point where i run the function.

```
function testconnection() {
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname;

    error_reporting(E_ERROR);

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    $dbconn = mysql_select_db($dbname);

    if ( !$conn ) { 
        return "connfailed";
    }

    if ( !$dbcon ) { 
        return "dbconnfailed";
    }
}
```

It stops any further building of the website.

All variables are defined. This function is just used to display an error message if it returns "dbconnfailed".

but even with `echo testconnection();` it displays nothing.

can be seen [here](http://edgclan.de/edit.php)

but I host this at a big company and on localhost via xampp
it isnt working on one.com but it is working on xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not add your connection to `$dbconn`

```
 $dbconn = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbconn);
```

Pls Don't use the deprecated and insecure mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli: Try this one..

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM usertable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli library

```
function testconnection() {
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname;

    error_reporting(E_ERROR);

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return "connfailed " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }    
    $dbconn = mysql_select_db($dbname);

    if(!$dbcon) { 
        return "dbconnfailed " . mysqli_error($dbconn);
    }
}
```